# GraphQL Apollo Mutation String cannot represent value with passed in array

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, resolver

I have a resolver Mutation in Apollo setup with the following code

```
Mutation: {
    sendInvite: async (parent, args: MutationSendInviteArgs, context) => {
      console.log('args email >>>>> ', args);
      // create invite code
      // add to invite container
      // send email with invite
      const emailSent = true;
      const emailMessage = 'sent invite';
      // is the record added by the api connector? ---> look into this
      return {
        success: emailSent,
        message: emailMessage,
        email:args.email
      }
    }
  }
```

I run the following mutation in playground

```
mutation{
  sendInvite(email:["anders@email.org","anders@email.com"]){
    email
    success
    message
  }
}
```

and I get the following response

```
 "message": "String cannot represent value: [\"anders@email.org\", \"anders@email.com\"]",
```

Oh and Heres my Mutation schema

```
type Mutation {
  sendInvite(email: [String]): Invite
}
```

```
type Invite {
  email: String!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
}
```

How do I return the email so it's an array that I can map over?

**Well actually I would like to return array of sendInvite field, so there were multiple success messages, emails and messages**

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: as always ... use variables, not hardcoded values ... https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: Thanks, I also had to change other things so have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Had to do the following

```
type Invite {
  InviteArray: [InviteArray!]
}

type InviteArray {
  email: String!
  verified: Boolean!
  success: Boolean!
  message: String!
}
```

```
let items = args.email.map((item) =>{
        return {email: item}
      })
      console.log("test >>>> ", test)
      return {
        InviteArray:items
      }
```

Comment: The type should be named `InviteItem`, not `InviteArray`